Azure: Add Mail.Send permission to app (Available permissions not showing)
I'm trying to code something where users will connect using their Microsoft account and will then be able to send an email that will be sent through their Microsoft email address.
I was able to set the authentication without any issue, but now that I try sending an email, it is not working, and I suspect it is because I don't have the required permission in Azure for my app.
I tried adding the GRAPH permission for Mail.Send, but unfortunately only two options are showing:

What I am missing to be able to see and add the other types of permissions?
I tried setting up a completely new app and that didn't solve my issue.

If your app registration is created in B2C tenant supporting user flows, it contains only Microsoft Graph offline_access and openid as Delegated permissions.
Initially, I created one application in Azure AD B2C tenant with supported account type as "Accounts in any identity provider or organizational directory (for authenticating users with user flows)":

These type of applications won't be having Delegated Microsoft Graph permissions other than offline_access and openid as below:

To resolve this, you need to switch to normal Azure AD tenant and create application with supported account type as "Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Microsoft Entra ID tenant - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)":

You can add Mail.Send Microsoft Graph permission of Delegated type in this application successfully as below:

